# google app engine deploy to two difference accounts from same machine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven

Using the google app engine maven plugin when a deploy is performed, the browser opens and an oauth key is copied.

However, I want to use two different google accounts from the same laptop and have laready previously registered one oauth key, but now want to use another. I never get prompted for a key and the deploy fails as the application id is not correct, which is expected.

Is there any way to use two different google accounts with app engine sdk ?

I can deploy the app OK using a different machine as it is setup with the correct account.

(this would not be a problem if push to deploy/pipeline worked, but it doesn't)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have more than one account register with the SDK, you should use [gcloud Command Line Tool](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/).

Once you have [login](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login) multiple accounts, `$ gcloud auth list` should yield a list of accounts. Switching is as simple as running ``` $ gcloud config set account ``ACCOUNT'' ``` which should make relevant tokens active and will allow you to use appcfg.[py|sh] with the selected account.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in your home directory, you should find a couple of files used by `appcfg`: `.appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java` and `.appcfg_cookies`.  Deleting the former (I think) will prompt `appcfg` to retrigger the oauth process.

So... I guess if you have multiple oauth token files, you can create a short shell script that takes the username as an argument then copies the oauth token file you need to `.appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java` just before the appcfg update.

Comment: I probably won't bother tbh, and will just wait til they sort out the push to deploy/pipeline feature

Comment: [gcloud Tool](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/#gcloud.auth) handles this use case by now.